# Problems with subqueries using Sakila

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the Sakila DB, i am trying to get the Country name, the number of cities that a country have, and the number of addresses of a country

Using the next query i get the country and the cities number

```
 SELECT CO.country,COUNT(CI.city_id)
FROM city CI
INNER JOIN country CO ON CO.country_id = CI.country_id
GROUP BY CO.country;
```

Using this other one i get the addresses number

```
SELECT CO.country,COUNT(A.address_id)
FROM city CI
INNER JOIN address A ON A.city_id=CI.city_id
INNER JOIN country CO ON CI.country_id=CO.country_id
GROUP BY CO.country;
```

I was hinted to use Subqueries to get the desired results, but i can't find how to get all that in one table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a tricky problem.  Your join approach *can* be made to work, with some slight modifications.  The total count across each country group will give the number of addresses in that country.  But to get the city count for a country, we can count the *distinct* city names in each country group.  The need for `DISTINCT` here is that the join to the address table will cause each city name to replicated however many times an address appears in a given city.  Taking the distinct city count gets around this problem.

```
SELECT
    co.country_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ci.city_id) AS city_cnt,
    COUNT(a.city_id)           AS address_cnt
FROM country co
INNER JOIN city ci
    ON co.country_id = ci.country_id
INNER JOIN address a
    ON ci.city_id = a.city_id
GROUP BY
    co.country_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result using below sub query. This is basically to show how you can write it. Its recommended to use join(Refer answer from Tim Biegeleisen) than Sub queries as it gives good performance.

```
select 
    Co.Country,
    (Select COUNT(1) from City Ci where Ci.countryid=co.countryid) CityCount,
    (Select COUNT(1) from Address A Join city c on a.city_id=c.city_id where C.countryid=co.countryid) AddressCount
From Country Co
```